# What is the maximal number of $(n-2)$-linear spaces lying on a degree $d$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f$ be a degree $d\ge 2$ polynomial in $n$ variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, and consider the hypersurface $X=V(f)$ cut by $f$ in $\mathbb{A}^n$. Assume that $X$ contains finitely many affine spaces of dimension $n-2$, i.e. $f|_{L} \equiv 0$ only for finitely affine spaces $L \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ with $\dim(L)=n-2$. What is the largest number of $(n-2)$-dimensional affine spaces $X$ can contain?

1. Is the answer to the above question known? What is the best known upper bound on this number?
   I think it is not hard to give an upper bound of the form $d^{2n-2}$ by considering the Fano scheme $F_{n-2}(\bar{X})$ parameterizing $(n-2)$-linear spaces in the closure of $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, but I am looking for a bound of the form $d^C$ where $C$ is independent of $n$.
   Note that $X$ may be singular, and I would like to vary over all polynomials $f$ such that $X$ contains finitely many $(n-2)$-dimensional spaces.
2. What happens if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$? Is the maximal number of $(n-2)$-linear spaces (or an upper bound) known? Is it different than the characteristic zero case?
3. Are there concrete examples of polynomials $f$ such that $X$ contains many $(n-2)$-affine spaces (but still finitely many)? Are there examples attaining or close to attaining the maximum, in case 1) or 2) are known?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: There is an extensive literature on the case $n=3$ (usually in $\mathbb{P}^3$, not $\mathbb{A}^3$). See Segre, 1943 https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/os-14.1.86 for the bound $(d-2)(11d-6)$. That bound has been improved, but the precise bound isn't known. I don't know any literature where $n$ varies.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer It's possible this bound implies a bound for all $n$. If you take your hypersurface and slice by a generic 3-dimensional linear subspace, all of the finitely many $n-2$-dimensional linear spaces will become lines on the slice. The problematic case is then when the generic slice is a ruled surface, but plausibly one can classify these surfaces and handle them separately.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thanks! I know Segre's paper, but I think it deals with a smooth variety, I want to also consider singular ones. Do you know any literature studying the singular case as well (say, for projective surfaces)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any. There are a lot of papers, though!

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks! That's a nice argument to bootstrap the surface case - a colleague suggested something along the same lines and it seems to work. If $d>2$ then I think a general surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is non-ruled, but our slice may not be generic (i.e. if we start with a singular hypersurface, every slice may be singular). Do you see a case when the generic slice is actually ruled? It seems surprising that something like that can happen.

Comment: Sure, if our hypersurface is defined by a quadratic polynomial then the slice will be even doubly ruled, and if the hypersurface is defined by a polynomial that depends on only two of the variables then a slice will be singular and ruled (but this is ruled out by your hypothesis that there are only finitely many affine subspaces).

Comment: In higher dimension, the problem one usually considers is the maximal number of linear subspaces of the hypersurface such that the dimension of the hypersurface is precisely twice the dimension of the linear subspace.  I have an upper bound in this case, written in an appendix to an article of Tim Browning and Roger Heath-Brown.  As David says, very little is known even in dimension $3$, except that we *do* know that Segre's upper bound is not always sharp, nor is there a standard lower bound of $3d^2$ that arises from considering Fermat hypersurfaces.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks for the comment, I know your appendix, and the proof there is very nice. I allow $X$ to be singular, so the setting is slightly different, and I am interested in an upper bound on the number of linear spaces of maximal dimension ($n-2$ when $X$ is a non ($n-2$)-ruled hypersurface) for reasons similar to Browning and Heath-Brown.